# Unable to synchronize the image acquisition/display with PI camera

Tags: c++, qt, camera, qt5

I have tried to develope a GUI (“PICamCtrl”) to control a Princento Instruments camera using C++ and Qt 5.2.0.

In the main GUI (“PICamCtrl”), there is a toggle button called “pBnStart” which starts/stops the PI camera data acquisition; there is a second button to initiate a sub-window (PICamShow) for the camera image display.

The  `SIGNAL(toggled(bool))` of pBnStart is connected with a slot `slotpBnStartToggled(bool)` in the constructor of class “PICamCtrl” as below:

```
connect(ui.pBnStart, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(slotpBnStartToggled(bool)));
```

`slotpBnStartToggled` is defined as below:

```
void PICamCtrl::slotpBnStartToggled(bool checked) {
   QString pBnStartText = checked ? "Stop" : "Start";
   ui.pBnStart->setText(pBnStartText);

   if(checked) 
   {
      ifAcquire = true;     
      slotAcquire();                            
   }
   else
   {
      ifAcquire = false;
   }                    
}
```

`slotpBnStartToggled` mainly keeps the camera acquiring data when it’s pressed down by setting a bool variable ifAcquire to be true, and vice versa.

`slotAcquire` is:

```
void PICamCtrl::slotAcquire()
{
   if(ifAcquire)
   {
      Picam_Acquire(hDevice,BUFFER_DEPTH,TIMEOUT,&available, &acq_errors);      
      QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(slotAcquire()));     
   }
}
```

The problem is: when `pBnStar` is pressed down to activate camera acquisition using “Picam_Acquire”,  sub-window (PICamShow) for the camera image display takes several seconds to respond.

Is there any better way to synchronize the image acquisition/display? Is it because I used `QTimer::singleShot` in `slotAcquire()`?

///
main.cpp

```
#include "PICamCtrl.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
PICamCtrl w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
}
```

/// PICamCtrl.cpp

```
#include "PICamCtrl.h"
#include <QtGui/QIcon>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSize>
#include <qtimer.h>
PICamCtrl::PICamCtrl(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)   
    ,firstRun(true) 
    ,ifAcquire (false)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ui.pBnStart->setCheckable(true);    
    slotInitialize();

    //
    this->setFixedSize(250,500); move (10, 10 ); // http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/3399-set-QMainWindow-in-the-center-of-my-desktop
    this->setWindowIcon(QIcon("Resources/Moonit_App_Icon.png"));    
    //
    diagPIShow = new PIShow();
    diagPIShow->setFixedSize(500,500);    diagPIShow->move(700,10); 
    diagPIShow->setWindowIcon(QIcon("Resources/Moonit_App_Icon.png"));  
    //  
    connect(ui.pBnStart,    SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),       this,    SLOT(slotpBnStartToggled(bool))); 
    connect(ui.pBnStart,    SIGNAL(clicked()),           this,    SLOT(slotInitialize()));      
    connect(ui.pBnStart,    SIGNAL(clicked()),           this,    SLOT(slotAcquire())); 
    connect(ui.pBnPIShow,   SIGNAL(clicked()),           this,    SLOT(slotPIShowImage()));
    connect(this,           SIGNAL(signalPIShowImage()), this,    SLOT(slotPIShowImage())); 
}

PICamCtrl::~PICamCtrl()
{

}
pibool PICamCtrl::slotInitialize()
{
    if(firstRun)
    {
        firstRun = false;
        disconnect(ui.pBnStart,    SIGNAL(clicked()),         this, SLOT(slotInitialize()));        
        //
        if( (e = Picam_GetAvailableCameraIDs(&id,&id_cnt)) != PicamError_None)
        {           
            Picam_UninitializeLibrary();
            return false;
        }       
        if( ( e = PicamAdvanced_OpenCameraDevice( id, &hDevice ) ) != PicamError_None )
        {                       
            Picam_DestroyCameraIDs( id );
            Picam_UninitializeLibrary();
            return false;
        }   
        return true;
    }
}
    void PICamCtrl::slotpBnStartToggled(bool checked)
{
    QString pBnStartText = checked ? "Stop" : "Start";
    ui.pBnStart->setText(pBnStartText);
    if(checked)
    {       
        ifAcquire = true;       
        slotAcquire();                          
    }
    else
    {       
        ifAcquire = false;
    }           
}
void PICamCtrl::slotAcquire()
{
    if(ifAcquire)
    {
        e =  Picam_Acquire(hDevice,            BUFFER_DEPTH,            TIMEOUT,            &available,            &acq_errors );
        if( e == PicamError_None && acq_errors == PicamAcquisitionErrorsMask_None )
        {       
            ui.HintsLabel->setText(tr("Camera Data Acquired"));
        }
        else
        {
            if( e != PicamError_None )
            {
                ui.ErrorLabel->setText(tr("Acquisition failed"));                       
            }
            if( acq_errors != PicamAcquisitionErrorsMask_None )
            {
                ui.ErrorLabel->setText(tr("The following acquisition errors occurred:"));                          
            }
        }
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(slotAcquire()));
    }
}


void  PICamCtrl::slotPIShowImage()
{       
    if(diagPIShow != NULL)      
    {
        diagPIShow->show(); 
        ui.HintsLabel->setText(tr("Picam Show")); ui.HintsLabel->update();
    }
    Picam_GetParameterIntegerValue(hDevice,      PicamParameter_PixelFormat,      reinterpret_cast<piint*>( &format ) );
    Picam_GetParameterIntegerValue(hDevice,      PicamParameter_PixelBitDepth,    &bit_depth );
    switch (bit_depth)
    {               
    case 16:            
        {                   
            pUShort = (unsigned short *)available.initial_readout;
            //
            e = Picam_GetParameterRoisConstraint(hDevice, PicamParameter_Rois, PicamConstraintCategory_Required, &picamRoi_constraint); 
            Picam_GetParameterFloatingPointValue(hDevice,          PicamParameter_ExposureTime,         &exposure_time );
            /* Error check for width and height */
            if (e == PicamError_None)
            {
                /* Get width and height from constraints */
                totalWidth  = (piint)picamRoi_constraint->width_constraint.maximum;
                totalHeight = (piint)picamRoi_constraint->height_constraint.maximum;            
            }

            qi = new QImage(totalWidth, totalHeight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
            for (int i = 0; i < totalHeight; i++)
            {       
                for (int j = 0; j < totalWidth; j++)
                {               
                    qi->setPixel(j,i,qRgb((uint8_t)(pUShort[i*totalWidth+j]>>8),(uint8_t)(pUShort[i*totalWidth+j+1]>>8),(uint8_t)(pUShort[i*totalWidth+j+2]>>8)));                  
                }
            }       
            diagPIShow->ImageGraphScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*qi)); delete qi;
            diagPIShow->ui.ImageGraphView->setScene(diagPIShow->ImageGraphScene);
            diagPIShow->ui.ImageGraphView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignLeft);            
        }       
    }
}
```

///PICamCtrl.h

```
#ifndef PICAMCTRL_H
#define PICAMCTRL_H

#include "stdint.h"
#include "picam.h"
#include "picam_advanced.h"
#include "picam_em_calibration.h"
#include "picam_special.h"
#include "pil_platform.h"

#include "picam_advanced.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>  // for C++ strings
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_PICamCtrl.h"
#include "ui_Settings.h"
#include "Settings.h"
#include "ui_PIShow.h"
#include "PIShow.h"

#include "qthread.h"

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#define FALSE               0
#define NUM_FRAMES          1      // number of frames to read
#define TIMEOUT             -1
#define BUFFER_DEPTH        1
#define SAMPLE_REGIONS      1   /* Multiple Region Count */
class PICamCtrl : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PICamCtrl(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~PICamCtrl();


private:
    Ui::PICamCtrlClass   ui;
    PIShow               *diagPIShow;
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *eve);
    //
    PicamError e;
    const PicamCameraID   *id;
    piint id_cnt;                // number of cameras detected
    const pichar *strings;
    PicamHandle     hDevice;
    const pichar    *string;    
    PicamAvailableData available;
    PicamAcquisitionErrorsMask acq_errors;
    piint bit_depth;
    PicamPixelFormat format;
    unsigned short *pUShort;
    const PicamRoisConstraint   *picamRoi_constraint;
    piint totalWidth;
    piint totalHeight;
    bool firstRun;
    bool  ifAcquire;
    QImage *qi;

signals:
    void   signalPIShowImage();
private slots:
    void   slotpBnStartToggled(bool);
    pibool slotInitialize();    
    void   slotAcquire();
    void   slotPIShowImage();   
};
#endif // PICAMCTRL_H
```

/// PIShow.cpp

```
#include "PIShow.h"

PIShow::PIShow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    //
    ImageGraphScene = new QGraphicsScene;

}

PIShow::~PIShow()
{

}
```

/// PIShow.h

```
#ifndef PISHOW_H
#define PISHOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "ui_PIShow.h"

class PIShow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PIShow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~PIShow();
    Ui::PIShow ui;
    QGraphicsScene *ImageGraphScene;

};

#endif // PISHOW_H
```

Comment: What you're doing is OK, if perhaps not the cleanest way. We don't know nearly enough about the `Picam_Acquire` method, nor about how the `PICamShow` window works to tell for sure. Please show a complete example - it doesn't have to be very long. Start with an empty `main.cpp` and add just enough to start the camera and show its data in a window.

Comment: Hi Kuba, thanks for the reply. Please find the updated questions where the main.cpp/PICamCtrl/cpp/PICamCtrl.h/PICamShow.cpp/PiCamshow.h have been added